# How do I sort mySQL regexp order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

```
ID test_varc

0 = "40:11,80:31",
1 = "40:12,80:32",
2 = "40:13,80:33",
3 = "40:14,80:34",
4 = "91:21,40:35",
5 = "91:22,40:36",
6 = "91:23,40:37",
7 = "40:15,91:24",
8 = "40:16,91:25",
9 = "40:17,91:26"

Output
ID test_varc

0 = "40:11,80:31",
1 = "40:12,80:32",
2 = "40:13,80:33",
3 = "40:14,80:34",
7 = "91:21,40:15",
8 = "91:22,40:16",
9 = "91:23,40:17",
4 = "40:35,91:24",
5 = "40:36,91:25",
6 = "40:37,91:26"
```

`select id, test_varc from test_table order by test_varc REGEXP '(40:\d+,)' desc`

Mysql order by regexp not working. how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: why do you not use **SUBSTRING_INDEX("40:11,80:31", ',', 1)** like this **select id, test_varc from test_table order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_varc, ',', 1);**

Comment: I cant really say I understand this. What are you expecting to be the outcome? Do you want it to be ordered by those starting with 40 first, and then what do you want after that? 40, 10, 20, 30, 50...? Or if you just want those that start with 40, why not just query them.

Comment: MySQL regular expressions don't use `\d` to match numbers, you have to use `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html for the full syntax of MySQL regular expressions.

Comment: Something like `order by substr(test_varc, position('40:'  in test_varc))`?

Comment: This makes no sense at all.  How do the ids change their values?

Comment: Those results don't even have the same test_varc values in them.

Comment: I want to sort the ones starting with 40 from small to Big or from big to small. 40 filter id : after filter option id.  my purpose sort filter options